# asp.net cache and virtual directory

Tags: asp.net, caching

Suppose I have an asp.net application "A" in IIS and "A" has two virtual directories (applications) "B" and "C" under it. We know that system.web.cache class is instantiated once for every application. Now

1>Will cache created under "B" be accessible to "C"?

2>Will cache created under "B" be accessible to "A" and vice versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, no. Caching can't cross Application boundaries. If you want to do that (or even cache across physical machines), you can use tools like [memcached](http://memcached.org/) or [Velocity by Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd861287.aspx).